# C++ iterators breaking in Visual C++ but not GNU g++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc

I am trying to learn more about list containers and how to iterate through them, but it seems that g++ has no problem with it, but Visual Studio C++ pukes all over the place!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

int main(){

   list <string> data;
   list <int>::iterator it;

   data.push_back("fee");
   data.push_back("fi");
   data.push_back("foo");
   data.push_back("fum");

   // something breaks back here ?!?!
  for(it=data.begin(); it!=data.end(); it++){
     cout << *it << endl;
  }

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: This code should make any compiler "puke" :) The only explanation is that you are trying to compile different code with each compiler.

Comment: I'd be _very_ surprised if GCC compiled this code.

Comment: @sbi, as would I.  GCC 4.1.2 rightly 'pukes' with the posted code and won't compile it for me

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try

```
list<string>::iterator
```

instead of

```
list<int>::iterator.
```

Comment: You're welcome.  On StackOverflow you can express your thanks by selecting this answer (or Jesse's) as the "accepted answer".

Answer (score 11):

gcc should "puke" here too (it does for me). You're assigning a `list<string>::iterator` to a `list<int>::iterator`, which are different types.

Answer (score 1):

That's why in C++ 11 auto datatype was introduced.

See the example below;

```
   // C++ 11 auto
  for (auto it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); it++) // it is list<string>::iterator
  { 
     cout << *it << endl; 
  }
```